# jqGrid 3.8.2 and 508 Complicance

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, accessibility, section508

I am using jqGrid on a site that needs to be [508 compliant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_508_Amendment_to_the_Rehabilitation_Act_of_1973).
One of the areas that I am running into trouble is wrapping the form inputs in the grid, currently it is a checkbox, with a label tag.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I couldn't get this to work, I had to use "datatables" instead.
I hope that doesn't disillusion people, I still love jqGrid, but I need something 508 compliant, even if it feels hacky and weird.